# python asyncio explanations and signals handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I've this code to test how does asyncio works:

```python
stop = False


async def subcoro():
    # same result even with a range of 30
    for i in range(30000):
        pass

async def first():
    global stop
    while not stop:
        await subcoro()
        # without sleep no signal is triggered
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


async def main(loop):
    coro = asyncio.ensure_future(first())
    await asyncio.wait([coro], loop=loop)


def end():
    global stop
    stop = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for signame in ('SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'):
        loop.add_signal_handler(getattr(signal, signame), end)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.ensure_future(main(loop)))
    finally:
        loop.close()
        print('Bye!')
```

Why I've to make `first()` sleeps for a while (even less than 0.1) to make the program handle the signals?
Is there another way to gracefully shutdown all coroutines and event loop?

UPDATE:
On python-forum.org they told me to read at [PEP-0492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) but it didn't provide any solution or suggestion.

UPDATE2:
My real application: https://github.com/FedericoTorsello/Embedded/tree/serialIO

Comment: Can you please make us a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your problem inside of your question, please ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, but the application in the link is quite 'minimal' (connect to arduino, set reader thread and run coroutines).
I figured out that the problem is the call to a function in an another thread who reads data from the serial that is not well handled in asyncio loop. I'll try to switch to the experimental serial.aio of figure out how to wrap the function `write_line` into a coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

I like this question, first thing I tried is to `strace` both:

With the `sleep` I see a lot of `epoll` (to wait the signal, which is "forwarded" via a socket, typically to comply with the atomicity required by the treatment of a received signal).

Without the `sleep` there's no `epoll`, so the signal is received by the process, the information is pushed on the socket, but never read.

Why is that ? From a semantical point of view, the:

```
while not stop:
    await subcoro()
```

is "unbreakable", in the sense of

> `await` similarly to `yield from`, suspends execution of [the] coroutine until [the] awaitable completes and returns the result data.

But as your `subcoro` does not give back the hand to the loop, it will return "immediatly", so the "await" is satisfied and the loop loops again, never giving a chance for the main loop to catch up.

So you're really in an "infinite while loop", never giving back the hand to the main loop.

Now, with the `asyncio.sleep`, you're giving back the hand to the main loop, as obviously, the implementation of `asyncio.sleep` does it so the main loop can do something else during the sleep duration, like checking for network events, like signal received on sockets. There's another way to explicitly give back the hand to the loop, is an empty "yield", like:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def cooperate():
    yield
    return
```

Now calling `await cooperate()` has the same effect as `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)` without actually sleeping, which is what `asyncio.sleep` does when given a delay of `0`:

```
@coroutine
def sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
    """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
    if delay == 0:
        yield
        return result
    [...]
```

From an implementation point of view, now:

With the sleep, `asyncio.base_events.BaseEventLoop._run_once` is called repeatedly, but never returns without the `sleep`, probably because your `first` never returns to it, I did not check it in depth.

To conclude:
`subcoro` is meaningless as is, and in a real world application, it will give back some time to the main loop, typically by calling the network, or waiting for anything.

Comment: hi! In my real application my `subcoro` actually send post data to a sever with aiohttp and my `first` read from a queue of messages and calls the `subcoro` (if the message need to be sended to the server, oterwise prints it).
looking at the sleep implementation I though your same thing but I don't get why I have to use it to stop my loop execution: I mean...it's not pythonic at all.

Comment: If your subcoro `await` a network request done by `aiohttp` and still you're not receiving your signal, please share us an example :-)

Comment: can you please provide a solution for the Q in code form.  Not the way, the solution we need.

Comment: @qrtLs the solution you need is to understand, no to copy/paste from stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Since loop.add.. the sig called function/handler can interact with the loop during signal handling (no need to pass it explicitly or other args like seen [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#set-signal-handlers-for-sigint-and-sigterm)). Following lib aiohttp/gunicorn eg, raise CustomException() and cleanup in all your coros `except CustmException:` clauses. Example:

```
import asyncio # etc

class GracefulExit(SystemExit):
    def __init__(self, msg=None, code=None):
        super(GracefulExit, self).__init__(msg)
        self.code = code


def handle_SIGTERM_exit(signum):
    logging.debug(f'handle {signal.Signals(signum)!r}')
    raise GracefulExit(code=0) # https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#set-signal-handlers-for-sigint-and-sigterm


def handle_SIGABRT_exit(signum): # else Fatal Python error: Aborted
    raise GracefulExit(code=1)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, functools.partial(handle_SIGTERM_exit, signal.SIGTERM)) 
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGABRT, handle_SIGABRT_exit, signal.SIGABRT, None)
    # add other coros to loop (that catch or finally:) 

asyncio.run(main())
```